# Recurrence Relation Homework Struggles

Tags: recurrence

Here's the question:
Solve the recurrence by obtaining a theta bound for T(n) given that T(1) = theta(1).

```
T(n) = n + T(n-3)
```

Attempted Solution:

```
T(n) = T(n-6) + (n-3) + n  

= T(n-9) + (n-6) + (n-3) + n  

= T(n-(n-1)) + [(n-n) + (n-(n-3)) + (n-(n-6)) + ... + n]

= T(1) + [0 + 3 + 6 + ... + n]

= theta(1) = 3[1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n/3]

= theta(1) + [(n/3)(n/3 + 1)]/2

= theta(1) + (n^2+3n)/6
```

When I double check to see if the solution fits the recurrence, it doesn't work.

Comment: There must be a better place for this. All other 'recurrence relation' problems are closed 'off topic'. Mods, any ideas?

Comment: @new123456: really? I only see one [recurrence-relation] question closed - that's hardly "all" of them. That said I'd tend to agree it is off topic - this smells like math to me... :) @sephy: perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com/ might be better?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll ask around in the math sections

Comment: Does the answer below solve the issue? If it doesn't I'll take another look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was certainly illuminating, the final answer was (4+n)*(n-1)/6; although I only got there from random guessing and checking and have no clue how that worked.

Comment: That was a typo on my part.
What part of it did you not understand.
I'd be glad to clarify any part of it with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that you were getting the wrong summation.
It doesn't start at 0, since your last T function was T(n - (n-1)) , which means previous one was T(n-(n-4)). So the summation starts at 4, and goes up till n.

If you don't know how to find the summation of this, I'd suggest you look at some of the proofs from the summation formula. This is what the solution looks like.

```
T(n) = T(n-3) + n  

= T(n-6) + (n-3) + n  

= T(n-(n-1)) + [ (n-(n-4)) + (n-(n-7)) + ... + n]

= T(1) + [4 + 7 + ... + n]

= theta(1) + (4 + n) * (n - 1)/6
```